# Can Visual Studio 2010 help be viewed inside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS2010 and the first big disappointment was the lack of any obvious way to view help within Studio itself. I very much like the new feature of updating help from the internet (I prefer to use local help because it's faster), but the separate browser window is simply distracting. I would like to view help within another tab inside the Studio itself. Also, the lack of contents and index docking-bars like in the old Studio is annoying.

Can these be brought back? Google gave me no results. :(

Comment: I agree with you.  I miss the old MSDN, and don't like the fact it starts its own web server to serve up help, and everything seems to take twice as long as it did before.  Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted.  This is a VS extension to let you use local help in VS.

[HelpViewerKeywordIndex](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/4af86641-a302-4edf-9853-007bcc670b30)

Answer (score 1):

In the code below you must replace the `break` instruction with `try`, `catch` and `throw`.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace UGVPI
{

    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long p;
            p = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long q = 2;
            while (q < p)
            {
                if (p % q == 0)
                    break;
                q = q + 1;
            }

            if (q < p)
                Console.WriteLine("Not Prime");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Prime");

        }
        
    }
}
```